# Generate files with one input to multiply outputs

Tags: dart, dart-build

I'm trying to create a code generator that takes input a JSON file and generates multiple classes in multiple files.

And my question is, is it possible to create multiple files for one input using build from dart lang?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. There are currently many tools in available on pub.dev that have code generation. For creating a simple custom code generator, check out the package [`code_builder`](https://pub.dev/packages/code_builder) provided by the core Dart team.

You can use [`dart_style`](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_style) as well to format the output of the `code_builder` results.

Here is a simple example of the package in use (from the package's example):

```dart
import 'package:code_builder/code_builder.dart';
import 'package:dart_style/dart_style.dart';

final _dartfmt = DartFormatter();

// The string of the generated code for AnimalClass
String animalClass() {
  final animal = Class((b) => b
    ..name = 'Animal'
    ..extend = refer('Organism')
    ..methods.add(Method.returnsVoid((b) => b
      ..name = 'eat'
      ..body = refer('print').call([literalString('Yum!')]).code)));
  return _dartfmt.format('${animal.accept(DartEmitter())}');
}
```

In this example you can use the [`dart:io`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/dart-io-library.html) API to create a [`File`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File-class.html) and write the output from `animalClass()` (from the example) to the file:

```dart
final animalDart = File('animal.dart');

// write the new file to the disk
animalDart.createSync();

// write the contents of the class to the file
animalDart.writeAsStringSync(animalClass());
```

---

You can use the `File` API to read a `.json` from the path, then use [`jsonDecode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.2/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html) on the contents of the file to access the contents of the JSON config.